# How to change the checkbox state only on clicking on a confirm modal button

Tags: angular, devextreme

I have a checkbox to deactivate and activate a particular row in a grid. On clicking the checkbox to activate/deactivate, a modal dialog box is displayed with two buttons 'Yes' and 'No'. When I click on 'Yes', only then I need to change the state of checkbox to activate or deactivate state.

I'm using Angular 9.1. The checkbox is a [devExtereme](https://js.devexpress.com/) switch.

Comment: If your modal is an other component. Create an @Output event emitter in your modal compont and emit the value on yes/no button click. In your grid component you have to bind this output value to checkbox disabled property.

Comment: If you need further help. Please give a stackblitz demo

Comment: Please add the related code in the question!